# Copying everything recursively with grunt-contrib-copy, omitting part of the structure?

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-copy

Say I have this directory setup:

```
 +-- gruntfile.js
 |    
 +-- src/
 |  |  
 |  +-- lib/
 |     |
 |     +-- imgs/**
 |     |
 |     +-- js/**
```

And I want to create a distribution folder using [grunt-contrib-copy](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy):

```
 +-- gruntfile.js
 |    
 +-- app/
 |  |  
 |  +-- lib/
 |     |
 |     +-- imgs/**
 |     |
 |     +-- js/**
 |
 +-- src/**
```

Note that the `src` folder is not listed within the `dist` folder. So far, all my efforts end up like this:

```
 +-- gruntfile.js
 |    
 +-- app/
 |  |  
 |  +-- src/
 |     |
 |     +-- lib/
 |        |
 |        +-- imgs/**
 |        |
 |        +-- js/**
 +-- src/**
```

I've tried many different configurations, but here's the one I'm on currently:

```
{
  expand: true,
  src: ['src/lib/**'],
  dest: 'app/',
  flatten: false,
  filter: 'isFile'
}
```

Remember that I want to copy everything recursively below `src` into `app`, but without the `src` folder coming with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `cwd` property to your config and modify the `src`, so it looks like this:

```
{
  expand: true,
  cwd: 'src/',
  src: ['lib/**'],
  dest: 'app/',
  flatten: false,
  filter: 'isFile'
}
```

Comment: Correct. Interestingly I did come across `cwd` and figured it would help; but I was still referencing the grunt directory within the `src` hash: `['src/lib/**']` - which was dim of me. Thanks.

Comment: Hardly "dim".  The docs are vague and many plugins actually lack docs on what I consider core functions.